# Touch Duration in UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitouch

Is there a way to get the touch duration of a UITableViewCell without subclassing? The reason being I want to display a modal view controller when the user holds a cell and display a detail view when the user taps a cell. I already have a working app using default UITableViewCells (but recently found a need for the hold event) which is the reason I dont really want to have to use subclassing. Any thoughts?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with 3.2+ compatibility, you can add `UIGestureRecognizer` for different type of touches (long touch).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm taking a look at the docs now and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks very much this worked perfectly. I simply added the relevant gestureRecognizer to my cell and that was it! Magic.